# How to edit a current e-commerce database to add attributes with different quantities?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm currently editing an e-commerce site wherein I need to add attributes to the product and assign them different values. I have two tables for the products:

**tblproducts**

- rkeyPrimary
- productId
- productName
- quantity
- price

**tblprodqtylog**

- rkeyPrimary
- productId
- remaining
- adjQty

What is the best way to execute this?

Comment: can you please elaborate on *add attributes to product and assign different values*

Comment: Adding attributes such as colors and sizes that has their own number of stocks. For example: in a shirt, size medium just has 6 size large has 2

Comment: Unrelated: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have three tables, based on normalized design.

1. tblProducts - containing product information
2. tblProductVariant - containing product variants information (like color, size etc)
3. tblprodqtylog - containing
   product inventory movements. It will have product variant as quantity is specific to variant. Eg. size Small has 6 quantity and 2 got sold and remaining is 4.

**tblproducts**

- productId
- productName

**tblproductVariant**

- productvariantid
- productid
- color
- size
- Price
- Quantity

**tblprodqtylog**

- productvariantid
- remaining
- adjqty

Comment: what if a product does not have a variant?

Comment: As variant is being used for product log, i would suggest you to have default variant for the product. You can even keep default values for the productvariant attributes like color, size, price etc

Comment: that's great help. i'm gonna go ahead and try to do that. thank you so much.